# Cron job executing in all cluster nodes in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, cron

I have implemented cron job using `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 1 * * ?")`  in Spring Boot. And this app deployed using kubernates in clustered environment so this cron job executing in all nodes in clustered environment.

Can anyone please suggest to execute this cron job in one node only?

Note: we are not using any database and dealing with Kafka topics to read messages and sending to other systems using soap ws.

Comment: Its better to convert the cron task into an api and use task scheduler like https://cloud.google.com/scheduler

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@SchedulerLock`

Example:

```
@Scheduled( ... )
@SchedulerLock(name = "scheduledJobName")
public void job() {
   // do your task
}
```

Look at [this](https://github.com/lukas-krecan/ShedLock)

Comment: SchedulerLock will work without database? @Golam Mazid sajib

Comment: no. u can use database or  cache server (redis or hazelcast) etc

Comment: how SchedulerLock need to be configure with db or it will automatically handles? @Golam Mazid sajib

Comment: look at the link i provided. there is part `Configure LockProvider`